# Create a DataFrame and JavaRDD from literal values

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am coding a Spark application in Java, and I wonder how would I create DataFrame and/or JavaRDD from literal values.

For example I have 3 integers, say `(784512, 35, 40)` corresponding to fields / columns `(id, m_count, f_count)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`SparkContext.parallelize(...)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#parallelize(java.util.List)) to create a JavaRDD and [`SQLContext.createDataFrame(...)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD,%20java.lang.Class)) to create a dataframe.

```
JavaRDD rdd = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

If you are after creating a parallel list of objects with three values then you want:

```
  @Test                                                                                                 
  public void test() {                                                                   
      JavaSparkContext sc =  ...                                                    
      SQLContext sqlContext =  new SQLContext(sc);                                                      

      JavaRDD<Counter> counters = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(new Counter(784512, 35, 40)));           
      DataFrame countersDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(counters, Counter.class);                       

      System.out.println(counters.collect());                                                           
      System.out.println(countersDF.collectAsList());                                                           
  }                                                                                                     



  public static class Counter implements Serializable{                                                         
      private final int id;                                                                             
      private final int m_count;                                                                        
      private final int f_count;                                                                        

      Counter(int id, int m_count, int f_count) {                                                       
          this.id = id;                                                                                 
          this.m_count = m_count;                                                                       
          this.f_count = f_count;                                                                       
      }                                                                                                 

      public String toString() {                                                                        
          return id + " " + m_count + " "  + f_count;                                                   
      }    
      // getters                                                                                          
  }
```